# Implementing scheduled push notifications with quickblox and IOS sdk

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, quickblox

In my app, I would like to send a 'scheduled' push notification. I am using quickblox as push notification service. The push notification must be created from the app itself to be sent by quickblox at the set date/time. The purpose of the message will be to sent a content available flag, so the app can fetch data in the background.

Searching the documentation, I think this can be achieved with 'ApplePushEvent'. However I cannot find any further information on this. I tried to add the following code in the sendButtonDidPress section, to send myself a push notification delayed 5 minutes:

```
NSUInteger userID = ((QBUUser *)[_users objectAtIndex:[usersPickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]]).ID;


NSDate *date = [[NSDate alloc]init];
NSDate *fiveMinFromNow = [date dateByAddingTimeInterval:300];

QBMApplePushEvent *APEvent = [QBMApplePushEvent pushEvent];
APEvent.active = NO;
APEvent.name = @"test";
APEvent.type = QBMEventTypeOneShot;
APEvent.date = fiveMinFromNow;

APEvent.isDevelopmentEnvironment = YES;

APEvent.usersIDs = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", userID];


NSString *message = @"Testing APNS!";
NSMutableDictionary *payload = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
NSMutableDictionary *aps = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[aps setObject:@"default" forKey:QBMPushMessageSoundKey];
[aps setObject:message forKey:QBMPushMessageAlertKey];
[payload setObject:aps forKey:QBMPushMessageApsKey];


QBMPushMessage *Pushmessage = [[QBMPushMessage alloc] initWithPayload:payload];



APEvent.pushMessage = Pushmessage;

[QBMessages createEvent:APEvent delegate:self];



[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];

[messageBody resignFirstResponder];
```

However nothing happens and I receive a 'invalid byte sequence in UTF-8' error in NSLog.

Below is an extraction from the Log:

```
2014-04-28 11:32:52.508 Messages[1763:4603] +[QBMEvent messageToString:] -> message: {
payload = "{\"aps\":{\"sound\":\"default\",\"alert\":\"TestingAPNS\"}}";
}
2014-04-28 11:32:52.510 Messages[1763:4603] Performing async request: 

POST https://api.quickblox.com/events.xml

headers:{
    "QB-SDK" = "iOS 1.8.4";
    "Qb-Token" = 33360a8735e91da82e588ffdbd5cd462b52420cf;
    "QuickBlox-REST-API-Version" = "0.1.1";
}

parameters:{
    "event[date]" = 1398677872;
    "event[environment]" = development;
    "event[event_type]" = "one_shot";
    "event[message]" =     "payload=eyJhcHMiOnsic291bmQiOiJkZWZhdWx0IiwiYWxlcnQiOiJUZXN0aW5nQVBOUyJ9fQ==";
    "event[name]" = test;
    "event[notification_type]" = push;
    "event[user][ids]" = 1026331;
}
2014-04-28 11:32:52.700 Messages[1763:1903] Request finished, response:

headers:{
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = "*";
    "Cache-Control" = "no-cache";
    Connection = "keep-alive";
    "Content-Type" = "application/xml; charset=utf-8";
    Date = "Mon, 28 Apr 2014 09:32:53 GMT";
    "QB-Token-ExpirationDate" = "2014-04-28 11:32:43 UTC";
    "QuickBlox-REST-API-Version" = "0.1.1";
    Server = "nginx/1.0.15";
    Status = "422 Unprocessable Entity";
    "Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
    "X-Rack-Cache" = "invalidate, pass";
    "X-Request-Id" = b65b8c46d1bd4c316e0758f047f1f1b1;
    "X-Runtime" = "0.076002";
    "X-UA-Compatible" = "IE=Edge,chrome=1";
}

body:

error:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<errors type="array">
  <error>
     <code nil="true"/>
     <message>invalid byte sequence in UTF-8</message>
  </error>
 </errors>
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Kind regards,

Louwrens

Answer (score 1):

You should add one more parameter and change APEvent.type:

```
APEvent.pushType = QBMPushTypeAPNS;
APEvent.type = QBMEventTypeFixedDate;
```

try this, hope this help

More info about schedule pushes read here http://quickblox.com/developers/Messages#Create_event

Answer (score 0):

I got the content-available flag working with Quickblox

I used the following code from Louwren's (user3580713) question:

```
NSString *message = @"Testing APNS!";
NSMutableDictionary *payload = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
NSMutableDictionary *aps = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[aps setObject:@"default" forKey:QBMPushMessageSoundKey];
[aps setObject:message forKey:QBMPushMessageAlertKey];
[payload setObject:aps forKey:QBMPushMessageApsKey];


QBMPushMessage *Pushmessage = [[QBMPushMessage alloc] initWithPayload:payload];
```

and added the following line after setObject:message

```
[aps setObject:@"1" forKey:@"content-available"];
```

didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler now gets called when the iPhone is asleep. I was searching for a way to add the content-available tag and this question helped me figure it out. Thanks. Hope this helps somebody.